# git difference in `git ls-tree` and `git ls-files`, or, what is the proper way to push deleted files to another git

Tags: git

In my repo, I find that there are files that do NOT exist in `git ls-tree` but exist in `git ls-files`. What I did was:
in workspace dir

```
~/wsp$ git clone ~/repo/project1
~/wsp$ rm project1/file1
~/wsp$ git add -A
~/wsp$ git commit -m'deleted file1'
~/wsp$ git push
```

in repo dir

```
~/repo$ git log
<deleted file1 commit msg is there>
~/repo$ git ls-tree
<file1 is not in ls-tree>
~/repo$ git ls-files
<file1 is still there!>
~/repo$ find . -name file1
~/repo/file1
```

And so it seems that file1 still exists in repo dir although in workspace dir, file1 is deleted, git-rm'ed, commited, and pushed to repo.

How can I push deleted or renamed files in one git dir to another git dir?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are cloning from `~/vcs/project1` and pushing to it, why are you checking `~/repo`?

Comment: `git ls-tree` needs you to supply a tree, did `git ls-tree` just show you the usage guide? Also, `git ls-tree` doesn't act recursively unless you supply `-r`.

Comment: If `git ls-files` works in `~/repo` it implies that this is another non-bare clone of `~/vcs/project`. You'll need to merge/reset/rebase/checkout something to get the change pushed from `~/wsp` into the working directory for `~/repo`.

Comment: @shahbaz oops my bad, edited

Comment: @CharlesBailey to clarify, I am attempting to push to a repo which I have cloned before. I see that doing a 'merge' will only update the tree/index but not the actual files, at least for the case of removing files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not push into non-bare repositories**.

You changed the repo state of `~/repo`, but not the working directory. When you `git status` in `repo`, you will see that git thinks you manually did some changes, because your repo state does not match your working dir/index.

If you want the discrepancy to go away, you need to run `git reset --hard` in `repo`. But this will wipe out any changes you had in your working dir.

You should not have pushed to `repo` in the first place. You should only ever push to bare repos (repositories without a working copy). You can **pull** from non-bare repos. So the correct way to get the changes in `wsp` into `repo` is to go into `repo` and pull from `wsp`.

Or is there any specific reason why you need to push into a non-bare repo?

Comment: I am trying to setup a git repo for my team. No specific reason why I should not got into 'repo' and pull from 'wsp'. Thanks